# Applying protected page to only 1 page within a page category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a sub-page (lack of a better term) password protected. This sub page is part of a group of pages which has a sub navigation on our wordpress site.

Under pages we have:

- Exhibitors

  - Who should exhibit
  - Payment
  - Costing
  - Exhibitor Zone (this is the page I am trying to make password protected)

When I add a password, it makes the entire Exhibitors page block password protected, if I remove the password it removes all of the passwords in the block and makes them all public.

Is there a way for me to only add a password to that 1 sub page? I am using Wordpress 3.5.1 and also have a plugin installed ([multiple passwords for protected pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/baw-multiple-pass-for-protected-pages/installation/))

Comment: do you use the plugin for password protection or the built in visibility option in wp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tickbox under the plugin which needs to be ticked to exclude parent or linked pages from having the password applied to those individual pages.